# running mysql procedure select operation make many resultset

Tags: mysql, resultset, procedure

I use mysql procudure to select results.Like

```
delimiter //
DROP procedure IF EXISTS prd_action;
create procedure prd_action()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_userid int;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct user_id from friends where user_id > 30;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
OPEN cur;
       REPEAT
         FETCH cur into v_userid;   
if not done then
         select * from friends where user_id = v_usetid
end if;
                UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur;
END//
delimiter
```

the resultset1,resultset2,...,resultset10 they are the resultsets,but I want them combine into one resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
DROP procedure IF EXISTS prd_action;
create procedure prd_action()
BEGIN
         select * from friends f
         where user_id > 30;

END//
delimiter ;
```

**----- EDIT ----**
If v_usetid parameter has to be used instead of 30, try this code:

```
create procedure prd_action(v_userid int)
BEGIN
         select * from friends f
         where user_id > v_userid;

END/
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f717d/3

Comment: @user3044480 I've added an example how to use parameter instead of constant